# "Opencart > Sales > Orders" multiple "Print Invoice" or "Print Shipping List" does not work

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, invoice

**Opencart**: v.2.1.0.2 (no core files are modified)

Inside Opencart's dashboard go to `SALES > ORDERS` and check (for example) the first two orders.
Then click on the *print icon* (top right of the page).
The standard behavior is that a new window (tab) will popup with the details of the (two) orders in "print mode".

What happens in my case is that a new window (tab) opens and not showing the orders details but the whole list of orders as if you have gone `SALES > ORDERS`.

What I have tried so far:
1. Cloned the e-Shop from example.com to dev.example.com
2. I have disabled all **Modifications** & **VQMOD**
3. I have tested the e-Shop with php **v.5.6.x**, **v.7.0.x**, **v.7.1.x** & **v.7.2.x**
4. And the most weird thing... In the same server on another domain (e-Shop) with the same "specs", IT WORKS!

Does anyone has experience something like this?
Can anyone suggest any kind of debugging?

Comment: The controller that passes the order_id(s) to the order_invoice (print template) is the file: admin/controller/sale/order.php.

In the file, search for code: if (isset($this->request->post['selected'])) {
   $orders = $this->request->post['selected'];
  } elseif (isset($this->request->get['order_id'])) {
   $orders[] = $this->request->get['order_id'];
  }

this is the part of the code that gets either one order_id or all selected. If you print_r the selected, and you see a big array of ids, that means that the print button gets all orders in the list as selected.

Comment: @Konstantinos, something really weird is happening because when I insert in `admin/controller/sale/order.php` this `$this->log->write($this->request->post['selected']);` or this `$this->log->write($this->request->get['order_id']);`, **System > Tools > Error Log** is empty!